C: Print from thread before thread terminates
I am using a boost, but my general question is:
Let's say I have this situation:
// thread create
pthread_create(&thread_ptr, NULL, runner, NULL);

// thread join/killed
pthread_join(thread_ptr, NULL);

Without modifying the runner function, is it possible for me to run a function/print details before the thread joins or before it is killed?
I have tried modifying the runner function. And for getting specific information from threads, I simply write them to a file and get the thread specific data.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

The quick and dirty way is to set a global variable that prevents the main thread from calling join before the spawned thread is finished. Use it to trap the main thread in a loop that terminates when the spawned thread changes the global variable.

Why wouldn't you be able to do this? Threads all run in the same address space, so the thread can write to a global variable or file, and the main thread can read them. You'll need some kind of synchronization so the main thread will know when the thread has written the data. You can use a semaphore for this.

Of course, that will probably require modifying the runner function, so it will synchronize using the semaphore.

As far as I can see, you can only do this from within the runner function. pthread_join doesn't terminate the thread, it just waits for it to exit. You could probably create a generic wrapper that did this. You initialize the wrapper with runner and then pass that to pthread_create.


Without modifying the runner function, is it possible for me to run a function/print details before the thread joins or before it is killed?

I take you to mean that messages are to be triggered by thread termination.  You can approach this by wrapping the runner function to register a cleanup handler:
void diagnose(void *message) {
    fputs((char *) message, stderr);
}

void *wrapper(void *arg) {
    pthread_cleanup_push(diagnose, "Thread terminating\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return runner(arg);
}

You then use wrapper instead of runner as your thread function.  That will dispatch the message whether the thread is canceled, returns from the thread function, or calls pthread_exit().  That particular wrapper won't message if the thread is terminated by a signal (except inasmuch as thread cancellation might use signals), but you could register a signal handler for that purpose.  Of course, the whole process would be terminating then.
Pthreads does not provide a means to associate any kind of messaging or other event handling with a thread externally, however.  It has to be controlled by the thread function.

Note the caveats in the POSIX specification of pthread_cleanup_push().  To be POSIX-compliant, your wrapper needs to become: void *wrapper(void *arg) { pthread_cleanup_push(diagnose, "Thread terminating\n"); void *rv = runner(arg); pthread_cleanup_pop(1); return rv; } — the cleanup calls must be used in pairs.  Use 0 instead of 1 if you do not want the cleanup function called on a normal exit.

Thank you, @JonathanLeffler.  Fixed.  I believe the variation I've chosen is compliant, and it moots the question of the value of the pthread_cleanup_pop() argument.

The POSIX specification states: The effect of the use of return, break, continue, and goto to prematurely leave a code block described by a pair of pthread_cleanup_push() and pthread_cleanup_pop() functions calls is undefined.  I think your revision falls foul of that undefined behaviour.
